# How to check if numbers in a list add up to a certain number?

Tags: python, list

e.g 
a = [7,8,8,9,4]
--> would give three points. Since **7 + 8** (8 at index --> 0), **7 + 8** (8 at index --> 1), **9 + 4** all equal 15

How do you write a code to do this in python?

Comment: Since when does `9 + 4 == 15`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all the 2-value combinations in your original list

```
>>> a = [7,8,8,9,4]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
[(7, 8), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 4), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 4), (8, 9), (8, 4), (9, 4)]
```

Then use a list comprehension to check if their sum equals your value

```
>>> total = 15
>>> [i for i in itertools.combinations(a, 2) if sum(i) == total]
[(7, 8), (7, 8)]
```